# Problems regarding reading words from a text file

Tags: java, file-io, io

The programme reads words from an existing file, changes their order and writes the words to the same file. The problem is, it does not read the words from the file, and it immediately throws an IOE exception. The user writes the filepath to the file. Here is part of the code, responsible for file reading;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordOrder {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> LinesList;
    public ArrayList<String> Words_per_line_list;
    protected String FileName;
    public WordOrder(){
        LinesList = new ArrayList<>();
        Words_per_line_list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void wordReading() throws IOException{
        String word_to_be_read;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println ("Enter the path of the file, e.g. D:/Folder/File.txt");
            FileName = scan.nextLine ();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (FileName));
            if(in.read () == -1){
                throw new IOException ("File does not exist or cannot be accessed");
            }
            System.out.println ("Test");
            int c, i =0;
            while(in.readLine() != null) {
                LinesList.add(i, Words_per_line_list);
                while ((c = in.read ()) != -1) {
                    word_to_be_read = in.readLine ();
                    Words_per_line_list.add(c, word_to_be_read);
                    System.out.println ("Test");
                }
                i++;
            }
            }
}
```

And here is the code, where the above method gets called

```
        try {
            wordReading();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println ("Hello, welcome to the WordSwapper. Please choose an operation. Press 1 to swap two lines, press 2 to swap two words within different lines.");
            byte choice = scan.nextByte ();
            scan.nextLine ();
            switch (choice) {
                case (1) -> swapLines ();
                case (2) -> swapWords ();
                default -> System.out.println ("Invalid choice. Please try again");
            }
            wordWriting ();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ie) {
            System.out.println ("Please enter an Integer");
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println ("File reading/writing has failed");
        }
```

It throws the exception of the bottom method ("File reading/writing has failed.")

Comment: Please include the exception stack trace and point out the line it is thrown from.

Comment: @Torben It is a manually thrown exception. I'll edit the post to show where and what is thrown

Comment: The part you filled in is not the exception being thrown. It's the error message you generated after you've discarded all the useful information that was in the actual exception. Please use `ioe.printStackTrace()` to log the error instead.

Comment: @Torben Here is the logged exception ```java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Java Projects\SAP (Access is denied)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108)
 at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
 at com.company.WordOrder.wordReading(WordOrder.java:22)
 at com.company.WordOrder.Program(WordOrder.java:94)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:6)```

Comment: This question is closed. I solved it.